# How do I achieve this format using sql server query

Tags: sql-server-2008

`Select * from #table` gives me this

[image: What I have]

What I want is this.

[image: What i want]

How will I write a query for this? Is this a type of Pivot?

Answer (score 1):

You need a *Dynamic Pivot* :

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('YourTable','U') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE YourTable
CREATE TABLE YourTable (Name VARCHAR(100), VALUE INT)
INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES
('A', 25),
('B', 30),
('A', 35),
('B', 40),
('A', 45)

DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(1000), @ColumnAs VARCHAR(4000),@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ',' + '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), number, 121) + ']'
                         FROM   master..spt_values N
                         WHERE  n.number BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
                                                        FROM YourTable
                                                        GROUP BY Name
                                                        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
                                AND TYPE = 'P'
                         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @ColumnAs = REPLACE(@Columns,'],[','] as [Value],[') + 'as [Value]'

SET @sql = 'select [Name],' + @ColumnAs +'
from
(
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by Name order by value) as [rn] from YourTable
) tab pivot
(
    max([Value])
    for rn in(' + @Columns +')
) as pvt'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```